# How to get REST parameters in HTML

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

I have created a REST webservice (and its client on Android) which can create user and make user sign in.But thats fine for Android .Since my URL is not exposed in Android.

My REST root path is : `http://localhost:8080/Mysite/rest/site`

I have certain REST methods like :

```
@Path("/create")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED){}

@Path("/{user}/createmessage")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED){}
```

You can see in second method the parameter `{user}` in `@Path("/{user}/createmessage")`.
That will be taken care by REST when calling from Android as it will susbstitue the username `{user}`  in HTTP Post request.

Now i need to make the WebClient.And i have the form as :

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/MySite/rest/site/{user}/createmessage" method="post">
<label for="title">Message Title : </label>
<input name="title" />
<label for="message">Message : </label>
<input name="message"/>
```

And thats for certain that this line is having error :
`<form action="http://localhost:8080/MySite/rest/site/{user}/createmessage" method="post">`

As `{user}` cannot be transmitted by HTML.

How to get the REST parameters from REST webservice in HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{user} is a notation to refer to a dynamic path segment used as a parameter. It is used by JAX-RS to denote the parameter name and location in the URI. It is not intended to be passed as is, but to be replaced with the actual parameter for the query.

It would help to see the signature of the REST method to provide some context as to what is expected, but chances are it's expecting some sort of id?
So if you want to create a message for user 123, you'd make your form action URL as below:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/MySite/rest/site/123/createmessage">
```

Comment: but thats i suppose is with the REST service how to let REST pass that id to HTML so it can replace `{user}` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean letting "REST pass that id to HTML". JAX-RS is a web service framework which has nothing to do with HTML. It's already kind of odd you'd call a REST service from an HTML form imho, but whatever web templating engine you use (JSP? JSF?) would be the technology involved in passing that parameter e.g.
<form action="http://localhost:8080/MySite/rest/site/<c:out value="#{myBean.userId}"/>/createmessage">